# Parse Server with independent workers

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, architecture, server, parse-server

Image we want to check two weeks after a user's registration if she has been active and otherwise I want to notify her.

To achieve this we currently use the following setup (this runs on Heroku):

[image: parse server in center]

The parse server puts a task into the redis queue. The worker fetches tasks from that queue. Then it performs checks on the activity of the user. For this it needs to access the parse server to fetch that information. This puts additional load on our api.

I image the following scenario to be better:

[image]

I wonder: is it possible to achieve this scenario using parse server? (The worker dynos don't have a HTTP interface to run a parse server...)